# Is it possible to have multiple header rows in a virtual string tree?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I have a need for multiple fixed rows for the header of a virtual string view - something that looks like the effect you get if you set a `StringGrid`'s `FixedRows` property to a value greater than 1. Is there a way to achieve this?

Some searching on the Soft-Gems website and forums led me to a couple of mentions of an `AdvancedHeaderDraw` method and a `HeaderQueryElements` property on the virtual string tree, but I can't work out how to use them.

I also found a demo that uses `THeaderControls` to achieve a similar effect but there has to be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's nothing like this built in. But you could try the VT descendant labeled "Virtual Treeview desc. (nested headers)" on [this page](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview).

**Note from ten years later:** Please note that VT's home is not at Soft gems anymore but at [JAM software](https://www.jam-software.de/virtual-treeview/index.shtml) now but I couldn't find the relevant download there. Also I have no idea if the descendant still works with current VT versions.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: @Nat Fixed as far as possible.